# Method for adding testCases

Tags: java, testing, testng

I am running TestCases programatically like,

```
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng=new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { UserGroupTest.class }); 
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
```

I have kept 8 test cases inside `UserGroupTest.class`

Is it possible to add testcase by testCase instead of adding whole class file?? Because I want to run testcases under condition basis. How to do tat?

Comment: can you give any basic info about what you are doing? What language?  (I assumed java) Framework?

Comment: @simeon you should probably add some wiki for the `testng` tag. I thought it was a spelling error =P

Comment: @giddy indeed, I will try to do that today when I have some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to run certain methods from these classes, you have a few options:

- Put these methods in a group and call testng.setGroups(..).
- Create a testng.xml (in-memory is probably the easiest since you are using the API) that will mimic the following XML:

  ```
  <classes>
    <class name="test.methods.SampleMethod1">
      <methods>
        <include name="shouldRun1" />
        <include name="shouldRun2" />
  ```